# JQuery get only text of element not text of childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big table which I need to convert some text to another Unicode entities, but some cells contains another html elements for example:

```
<td>some text <span>another text</span></td>
```

I want to get `some text` only because I can get the first child `span` by:

```
children().eq(0)
```

I tried

```
$(this).text() //but gets all text inside the cell
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get `some text` like following.

```
this.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

**Example**

```js
$('td').click(function () {
    alert(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some text <span>another text</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Akam No, it isn't, this one include text nodes

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).childNodes is undefined`

Comment: @Akam `this.childNodes` not `$(this).childNodes`. This answer is good but limited to only the first one text node. In your case, this is for sure the most efficient way

Comment: yes its working perfect, how to make it work for `$('td#test')`? like this `($('td#test').this.childNodes[0].nodeValue)`

Comment: Use `$('td#test')[0]`. Like `$('td#test')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`. @Akam

Comment: what if the td contains another text after span? can we try same method?

Comment: Use `childNodes[2]` then. @Akam

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, you need to filter out its content to get textnode text:

```
$(this).contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text(); // >> "some text "
```

And this is where jQuery becomes funny:

```
$(this).contents().not(':not(:not(*))').text();  // >> "some text "
```

While:

```
$(this).contents().not('*').text(); // >> "" (empty string!!!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery you could clone the element and remove his childrens then get text :

```
$('td').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
alert( $('p').clone().children().remove().end().text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>some text <span>another text</span></p>
```

Comment: IMHO, no one should use this kind of code on a production website. This is very very slow and quite confusing

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff for your intervention/advice, and i think that will take milliseconds in such simple cases.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Ya that's correct but i'd be more concerned about readability

Comment: Yep and that's correct too.. thanks anyway, have a nice day.